# Multivariate linear bayesian regression in matlab with normal-gamma assumption for data

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, matlab

1. for the general case : data is normal-gamma (mean normal and sd is gamma) and I want to estimate the $b$ and $a$ distribution ( they assumed to be normal) in $y=bx+a$ using Bayesian regression. I know I need assumption for my priors but I think I have to be OK with most simplistic case. not very good in reading statistics literature to derive the code from heavy literature.
2. {trying to be more clear} piece of code is helpful as well as pseudo-code of how to do it. Here I explain the case I did for single parameter as an example. there are 2 ways actually by conditioning on ro/p (precision) or unconditional. Keep these pre-calculation: `Sxx<-sum((x-xbar)^2) , Syy<-sum((y-ybar)^2) , Sxy<-sum((x-xbar)(y-ybar)) , See<-sum( ( y-ybar-b(x-xbar))^2)` }

Posterior distribution for $\rho$ is Gamma with shape $(n-2)/2$ and scale $2/S_{ee}$.

Conditional on $\rho$, $\eta$ and $\beta$ are independent and normally distributed, $\eta$ has mean $y$ and precision $n\rho$, $\beta$  has mean $b$ and precision $S_{xx}\rho$.

Uncoditional: Marginal posterior distribution for $\eta$ and $\beta$. $\eta$ has nonstandard t distribution with: Center $\bar y$,  spread $(n(n-2)/S_{ee})-1/2$,  degrees of freedom $n-2$.

$\beta$ has nonstandard t distribution with:  Center $\bar y$, spread $(S_{xx}(n-2)/S_{ee})-1/2$,  degrees of freedom $n-2$.

$\eta$ and $\beta$ are uncorrelated but not independent when we marginalize out $\rho$.

I dont know how this could be for MultiVariate Case. I know I can use Winbugs but I need to write it in Matlab.

Comment: I tried to make the text more readable by introducing latex. Please check if there are no mistakes. And please consider rewriting the question to make it clearer.

Comment: there are a lot of views but no comments?

Comment: More of a comment then an answer:
I suppose that the multiple views without answer are due to the R tag while it is actually a Matlab question.

Comment: What is $\rho$ and what is $\eta$ and what is $\beta$?  What is the model?  Because of the reference to least squares you probably have $(y|a,b,x,\sigma^2)\sim Normal(a+bx,\sigma^2)$.  I think by "SD is gamma" you also mean $\sigma^2\sim gamma(.)$ - although usually we have inverse gamma for variance as this is conditionally conjugate - gamma usually leads to Laplace type distribution, while inverse gamma leads to t-distribution.  However you have not specified any priors for $a,b$ - what did you have in mind?

Comment: @probabilityislogic I think I edited the question while ago, but today I just realized I have moved on from this topic for years. The model was for using residuals of data minus model in signal processing-based fault detection. I wonder if there is any benefit to use a sequential bayesian method in real-time anomaly detection. I have left the report years ago , but I would be happy to finish it.